# Block iAds by general category

Tags: ios, iad

I'd like to prevent ads of specific categories (e.g. "financial") from being displayed within my iOS app(s). I can't hardly find any solution how to do that in the iAd documentation. Also searching Google and Stack Overflow did not bring up any solution.

Does anyone have a solution or is iAd really that limited compared to AdMob? Or am I just looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 0):

Blocking/allowing certain advertising categories for iAd is currently not possible. I would not hold out for this feature either as there has been little change with iAd's tools since its initial release.

If blocking certain advertising categories is highly important to you remove iAd and use AdMob exclusively. You can block/allow specific categories at [AdMob.com](https://apps.admob.com/#home).